# How to create fake text file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, readlines

How can I create a fake file object in Python that contains text? I'm trying to write unit tests for a method that takes in a file object and retrieves the text via `readlines()` then do some text manipulation. Please note I can't create an actual file on the file system. The solution has to be compatible with Python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is exactly what [`StringIO`/`cStringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) (renamed to [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) in Python 3) is for.

Comment: The solution has to be compatible with Python 2.7.3

Comment: @user1454693 The StringIO version is... or are you using a different 2.7.3 than the rest of the world?

Comment: @user1454693 StringIO is compatible with 2.7.3 and above.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could implement it yourself pretty easily especially since all you need is `readlines()`:

```
class FileSpoof:
     def __init__(self,my_text):
         self.my_text = my_text
     def readlines(self):
         return self.my_text.splitlines()
```

then just call it like:

```
somefake = FileSpoof("This is a bunch\nOf Text!")
print somefake.readlines()
```

That said the other answer is probably more correct.

Answer (score 4):

#### In Python3

```
import io
fake_file = io.StringIO("your text goes here") # takes string as arg
fake_file.read() # you can use fake_file object to do whatever you want
```

#### In Python2

```
import io
fake_file = io.StringIO(u"your text goes here") # takes unicode as argument
fake_file.read()  # you can use fake_file object to do whatever you want
```

For more info check docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy using [faker-file](https://pypi.org/project/faker-file/) (supported formats `BIN`, `CSV`, `DOCX`, `ICO`, `JPEG`, `PDF`, `PNG`, `PPTX`, `SVG`, `TXT`, `WEBP` and `ZIP`).

##### Installation

```bash
pip install faker-file[common]
```

##### Usage

```py
from faker import Faker
from faker_file.providers.txt_file import TxtFileProvider

FAKER = Faker()
FAKER.add_provider(TxtFileProvider)

file = FAKER.txt_file()
```

Check the [quick start](https://faker-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html) and [recipes](https://faker-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html) for more.